# using UnboundID's @LDAPGetter and @LDAPSetter

Tags: java, ldap, persistence, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Does anyone have a basic example of using these two annotations from [UnboundID's SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/persist/index.php) to persist objects in an LDAP directory?  I can't seem to find any info about the type of the argument to the `@LDAPSetter` method or the value returned from the `@LDAPGetter` method.

To put it another way, how do I fill in the `<?>`s:

```
/**
* Called when creating a Java object from an LDAP entry.
*/
@LDAPSetter(attribute="roleOccupants")
void initMembers(<?> occupants) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

/**
* Called when turning a Java object into an LDAP entry.
*/
@LDAPGetter(attribute="roleOccupants")
<?> storeMembers() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the value of the `roleOccupants` attribute.  One of the optional fields of the `@LDAPGetter` and `@LDAPSetter` annotations is `encoderClass`, which allows you to specify an object encoder that will be used to convert between LDAP attribute values and Java data types.  If you don't specify a custom encoder (and most of the time you shouldn't need to), then it will use the `DefaultObjectEncoder` class to perform the work, and it supports the following data types:

- boolean
- byte[]
- char[]
- double
- float
- int
- long
- short
- java.lang.Boolean
- java.lang.Double
- java.lang.Float
- java.lang.Integer
- java.lang.Long
- java.lang.Short
- java.lang.String
- java.lang.StringBuffer
- java.lang.StringBuilder
- java.math.BigDecimal
- java.math.BigInteger
- java.net.URI
- java.net.URL
- java.util.Date
- java.util.UUID
- java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
- java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong
- com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.DN
- com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.Filter
- com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPURL
- com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.RDN

It also supports arrays, lists, and sets of any of the above types, and any kind of enumeration.  See the class-level documentation for the [com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.persist.DefaultObjectEncoder](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/persist/DefaultObjectEncoder.html) class for a more complete description of the supported data types and any constraints with u.

So really, the data type that you choose depends on which of the above is most appropriate for the kind of information that is stored in the corresponding LDAP attribute.  In many cases, String may be the most appropriate, but in others you may rather have it treated as a number or a DN or a timestamp or something like that.  If none of the default types is acceptable, then you can create your own custom ObjectEncoder instance to perform whatever translation you want.

Comment: Thanks Neil.  I was looking in the wrong place and had just tracked it down when I saw your answer.  Would be nice if there was a link to that info on the [tutorial page](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/persist/LDAPGetterAndSetter.php) and in the javadocs for `@LDAPGetter` and `@LDAPSetter`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of usage for anyone else that's wondering.  It automatically loads user data from ldap when you read an `organizationalRole`.

### `UserRole` class:

```
@LDAPObject(structuralClass="organizationalRole", defaultParentDN="dc=Roles,dc=example,dc=com")
public class UserRole extends LDAPModel implements models.deadbolt.Role {

    @LDAPField(attribute="cn",inRDN=true,filterUsage=FilterUsage.ALWAYS_ALLOWED)
    public String name;

    private List<User> members;

    public List<User> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    /**
    * Called when creating a Java object from an LDAP entry.
    */
    @LDAPSetter(attribute="roleOccupant")
    void initMembers(String[] occupants) throws LDAPException {
        members = new ArrayList<User>();

        if (occupants == null || occupants.length == 0)
            return;

        for (String dn : occupants)
            members.add(User.findByDN(dn));

    }

    /**
    * Called when turning a Java object into an LDAP entry.
    */
    @LDAPGetter(attribute="roleOccupant")
    String[] storeMembers() {
        if (members == null)
            return null;

        String[] member_strings = new String[members.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++)
            member_strings[i] = members.get(i).getDN();

        return member_strings;
    }

}
```

### `User` class:

```
@LDAPObject(structuralClass="inetOrgPerson",
    auxiliaryClass={"mozillaOrgPerson","posixAccount","sambaSamAccount","shadowAccount"},
    defaultParentDN="dc=People,dc=example,dc=com")
public class User extends LDAPModel implements RoleHolder {

    ...

    @LDAPField(attribute="givenName",filterUsage=FilterUsage.ALWAYS_ALLOWED)
    public String fname;

    @LDAPField(attribute="sn",filterUsage=FilterUsage.ALWAYS_ALLOWED)
    public String lname;

    public static User findByDN(String dn) throws LDAPException {
        LDAPConnection conn = ...
        LDAPPersister<User> persister = LDAPPersister.getInstance(User.class);
        return persister.get(dn, conn);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the demonstration of how to initialize a persister